# How to set Org-mode heading color for level after 8?

Tags: org-mode

I can only set color and font-face for Level between 1 to 8. Is there a way to set heading color for Org Level 9 and beyond?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where can I find your `init.el` file? Your Emacs looks awesome!

Comment: I'm using Spacemacs and you can find it here, http://spacemacs.org/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can guess from your screenshot, the face for level 9 is the same as the face for level 1. You can confirm this by hitting `C-u C-x =` with your cursor on a level 9 headline which shows:

```
There are text properties here:
  face                 org-level-1
```

AFAICT, if you want a different face for level 9 (and further), it involves adding one or more new faces (with e.g. `defface`), changing the defconst `org-level-faces` (add your new face(s) there) and change the value of `org-n-level-faces`. e.g. the following should work (only lightly tested) :

```el
(progn
  (defface org-level-9 ;; originally copied from org-level-8
    (org-compatible-face nil ;; not inheriting from outline-9 because that does not exist
      '((((class color) (min-colors 16) (background light)) (:foreground "RosyBrown"))
        (((class color) (min-colors 16) (background dark)) (:foreground "LightSalmon"))
        (((class color) (min-colors 8)) (:foreground "green"))))
    "Face used for level 9 headlines."
    :group 'org-faces)
  (setq org-level-faces (append org-level-faces (list 'org-level-9)))
  (setq org-n-level-faces (length org-level-faces)))
```

Comment: What's the command bound to `C-u C-x =`?

Comment: I found it, it's `describe-text-properties`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on YoungFrog's answer:

```
(progn
  (progn
    (face-spec-set 'org-level-5 ;; originally copied from org-level-8
      (org-compatible-face nil ;; not inheriting from outline-9 because that does not exist
        '((((class color) (min-colors 16) (background light)) (:foreground "brightblue"))
          (((class color) (min-colors 16) (background dark)) (:foreground "brightblue"))
          (((class color) (min-colors 8)) (:foreground "green")))))
    (face-spec-set 'org-level-6 ;; originally copied from org-level-8
      (org-compatible-face nil ;; not inheriting from outline-9 because that does not exist
        '((((class color) (min-colors 16) (background light)) (:foreground "brightcyan"))
          (((class color) (min-colors 16) (background dark)) (:foreground "brightcyan"))
          (((class color) (min-colors 8)) (:foreground "green")))))
    (face-spec-set 'org-level-7 ;; originally copied from org-level-8
      (org-compatible-face nil ;; not inheriting from outline-9 because that does not exist
        '((((class color) (min-colors 16) (background light)) (:foreground "deepskyblue"))
          (((class color) (min-colors 16) (background dark)) (:foreground "deepskyblue"))
          (((class color) (min-colors 8)) (:foreground "green")))))
    (face-spec-set 'org-level-8 ;; originally copied from org-level-8
      (org-compatible-face nil ;; not inheriting from outline-9 because that does not exist
        '((((class color) (min-colors 16) (background light)) (:foreground "Purple"))
          (((class color) (min-colors 16) (background dark)) (:foreground "Purple"))
          (((class color) (min-colors 8)) (:foreground "green")))))
    (defface org-level-9 ;; originally copied from org-level-8
      (org-compatible-face nil ;; not inheriting from outline-9 because that does not exist
        '((((class color) (min-colors 16) (background light)) (:foreground "RosyBrown"))
          (((class color) (min-colors 16) (background dark)) (:foreground "LightSalmon"))
          (((class color) (min-colors 8)) (:foreground "green"))))
      "Face used for level 9 headlines."
      :group 'org-faces)
    (setq org-level-faces (append org-level-faces (list 'org-level-9)))
    (setq org-n-level-faces (length org-level-faces))))
```

Note that you can use `counsel-colors-emacs` to insert the colors if you counsel installed.